# What is causing a shadow copy of my Dragged control to be visible?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, drag-and-drop, .net-3.5

My form has two objects: a background image that takes up the entire screen, and a dragable dialog control that only takes up a portion of the screen. I am using Mouse events for dragging and dropping the dialog control within the background image.

My problem is that while dragging, there is a copy of the control that is visible at it's previous location.

What is causing this shadow copy to appear, and how can I prevent it from happening?

My code looks something like this:

```
private void dialog_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        _dialogDragStart = e.Location;
        dialog.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(dialog_MouseMove);
    }
}

private void dialog_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    dialog.MouseMove -= new MouseEventHandler(dialog_MouseMove);
    _isDragging.Value = false;
}

private void dialog_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var difference = new Point(e.Location.X - _dialogDragStart.X, e.Location.Y - _dialogDragStart.Y);

    if (!_isDragging.Value)
    {
        if (Math.Abs(difference.X) > SystemInformation.DragSize.Width || Math.Abs(difference.Y) > SystemInformation.DragSize.Height)
        {
            _isDragging.Value = true;
        }
    }
    else if (_isDragging.Value && !difference.IsEmpty)
    {
        DialogOffset = GetValidDialogOffset(DialogOffset.X + difference.X, DialogOffset.Y + difference.Y);

        this.Invalidate();
        this.Update();
    }
}
```

It should be noted that this entire UserControl contains a custom OnPaint event. The Paint event recalculates the Size and Location of the Dialog before painting it in a custom format. To get this working, I have simply adjusted the Location calculation to include the DialogOffset.

```
const int padding = 1;
const int shadowDepth = 3;
const int roudeCornerRadius = 5;

private void Paint(Graphics g, Rectangle clipRect)
{
    try
    {
        dialog.Size = GetSize();

        dialog.Location = new Point(
            ((backgroundImage.Width - dialog.Width) / 2) + DialogOffset.X,
            ((backgroundImage.Height - dialog.Height) / 2) + DialogOffset.Y);

        if (Image != null && !backgroundImage.ClientRectangle.IsEmpty)
        {
            Rectangle imageBounds = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, Image.Size);

            using (BufferedGraphics buffer = BufferedGraphicsManager.Current.Allocate(g, backgroundImage.ClientRectangle))
            {
                using (Bitmap img = ((Bitmap)backgroundImage).Clone(imageBounds, PixelFormat.Format16bppArgb1555) as Bitmap)
                {
                    buffer.Graphics.Clear(Color.White);
                    buffer.Graphics.DrawImage(img,backgroundImage.ClientRectangle, imageBounds, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                    buffer.Render(g);
                }
            }
        }

        //Create Rectangles
        Rectangle outerRect = dialog.ClientRectangle;
        Rectangle innerRect = new Rectangle(padding, padding, outerRect.Width - (padding + shadowDepth), outerRect.Height - (padding + shadowDepth));

        //create Paths
        using (GraphicsPath innerPath = new GraphicsPath())
        {
            GraphicsHelper.GetRoundedRect(innerPath, innerRect, roudeCornerRadius, 1, 1);

            //Assign outer rounded rectangle to the dialog's region property
            Region region = new Region(innerPath);
            if (dialog.Region != null)
                dialog.Region.Dispose();

            dialog.Region = region;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Log error
    }
}
```

I've seen suggestions to set the `DoubleBufferred` property to true, however its explicitly set to false in the existing code, and setting it to true causes no update at all while dragging.

I've tried taking a screenshot of the problem, however all screenshots only show one copy of the dialog control being dragged, even though I can clearly see a 2nd copy of the control on my screen while dragging.

What can be causing this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Is it simply a refresh issue?  Inject an `Invalidate()` on the background?  Perhaps show the `Paint` code...likely where it's at.

Comment: @DonBoitnott I tried running `Invalidate(); Update();` using `BeginInvoke`, however the same problem occurs. I'll try to simplify the Paint code and add it to the question. I'm not the author of it though, and am no winforms expert :)

Comment: Is this dialog supposed to be like an MDI child?  And is the `Paint` event you've provided for the `Form` or the dialog that you are dragging?

Comment: @DonBoitnott Yes, this is using a MDI interface. The entire UserControl is placed inside a MDI window and overlays another control. The Paint method is actually in the Presenter layer of a MVP application. The Paint method is for both the entire UserControl (Sorry, I said Form to simplify), and for the panel containing the `backgroundImage`

Comment: Is the dialog itself an actual `Form`?  You call for update in `dialog_MouseMove`, but what about the underlying background?  Something like `((MyUserControl)this.Parent).Invalidate(true);`?  Evidence:  is this "shadow" image affected when you drag the dialog back over it?

Comment: @DonBoitnott I wish I could catch a screenshot of it.... it basically behaves like when your Windows UI stops painting, and you can drag around windows and the previous window stays visible (I'm sure everyone has seen that one at least once in their life time), except the previous window disappears after a second or two. The dialog itself is actually a UserControl. Forms are added to our MDI interface that contain 4 separate "Screens" for the form, and this is one of them. When set, this UserControl becomes visible and the one currently visible gets hidden. I believe it uses a CAB Deck design

Comment: I don't think there is enough code posted to duplicate the issue.  Changing the size and location of a control during a paint event is questionable practice.  Can you show the code for `GetValidDialogOffset`?

Comment: @LarsTech Yeah, I think I might speak with the author of the code and find out why it's done this way. I've been testing a bit more and am realizing that part of the problem is a slow screen redraw - for example, the shadow copy of the dialog gets slowly erased starting from the top-left. `GetValidDialogOffset()` just checks the bounds and ensures that the dialog doesn't get dragged off the screen.

Comment: Hard to imagine how code can turn into this.  Probably some kind of hack to hide a problem with the form drawing its background too slowly.  Rip and tear is highly recommended here, just get rid of it all and simply update the Location property in the mouse event handler.  Slow background redraws are covered in other questions already and easy to fix.

Comment: @HansPassant That's the direction I think I'm going to attempt. I need to clear it with someone else first though. I've been able to narrow down the problem to the Paint method that is drawing the background image though, as commenting out that block of code fixes the problem (although of course, the background image no longer gets drawn then).